# Laravel : Password reset email check against user

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, laravel-5

I have the following code to send the password reset email to the users email which is working:

```
$response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink($request->only('email'),function($message)
{
    $message->subject('Password Reminder');
});
```

What i want is that user should write their `username` instead of email, And i will check the email against that username , And will send the email.So i came up with this idea.

```
    $usernameToEmail = User::where('name','=', Input::get('username'))->first();  

    $response = $this->passwords->sendResetLink(['name' => $usernameToEmail],function($message)
    {
        $message->subject('Password Reminder');
    });
```

Which is not working also.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: $email = $usernameToEmail->email , add this after user to email and use email vqriable in function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but your `$usernameToEmail` variable contains a `User` object, not an email string. Most likely you just need to add a method to your chain:

```
$usernameToEmail = User::where('name','=', Input::get('username'))->first()->email;
```

Comment: Ok its not working, The working code returns this :

`array:1 [▼
  "email" => "shafeekhaan@hotmail.com"
]`

from this `dd($request->only('email'));`

And your change returns this :

`array:1 [▼
  "name" => "shafeekhaan@hotmail.com"
]`

From this : `dd(['username' => $usernameToEmail]);`

Have a look

Comment: I got it, The thing was that i should be using email instead of name in the `sendResetLink()`